# Splitting words before and after '/' in using Regex

Tags: python, regex, python-re

Have the following string:

```
text = 'interesting/practical/useful'
```

I need to split it like `interesting / practical / useful` using Regex.

I'm trying this

```
newText = re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z](/)[a-zA-Z]', ' \g<0> ', text)
```

but it returns

```
interestin g/p ractica l/u seful
```

P.S. I have other texts in the Corpus that also have forward slashes that shouldn't be altered due to this operation, which is my I'm looking for regex patterns specifically with characters before and after the `'/'`.

Comment: Can't you just replace `'/'` with `' / '`?

Comment: Do it in a simple way: newText = ' / '.join('interesting/practical/useful'.split('/'))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use lookarounds for the letters before and after the `/`, so they're not included in the match.

```
newText = re.sub(r'(?<=[a-zA-Z])/(?=[a-zA-Z])', ' \g<0> ', text)
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm used to do it this way:

```
newText = re.sub(r'([a-zA-Z])/([a-zA-Z])', '\1 / \2', text)
```

`\1` and `\2` are the references on the first and second founded expressions in the brakets `()`

In plain English it means: look for any letter, a slash, a letter and change them with the founded letter, a space, a slash, a space and the second founded letter.